# Ctrl + C vs Ctrl + Z for pausing repo sync?

Tags: android, bash, git, repository, repo

I am using `repo sync` to download LineageOS 15.1 after using the below init command.

```
repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-15.1
```

I need to pause the sync everyday due to my internet quota restrictions. How to achieve that ?

I have seen a number of posts telling to suspend/kill the job by using :-

- `CTRL + Z` and resume it later using `fg` (provided I don't shutdown
  my PC)
- `CTRL + C` and then again using `repo sync` and it is supposed to pick it up from where it left off by skimming through the files already downloaded in the .repo folder (shutdown is allowed)

But neither of them seem to work for the users (i didn't try yet). So please let me know which one can actually work or has the highest chance of working.

References

1. [Pausing & Resume Android Repo Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555835/pausing-resume-android-repo-sync)
2. [[TRICK] Pause the repo sync | Android Development and Hacking](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2666561)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to try so I choose <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> option and it actually worked for me.

When I ran `repo sync` again, I could see it skimming through already fetched files and there was a word ***resuming transfer*** mentioned right before it started downloading again. So I think its safe to say that this option can be used to effectively ***pause*** `repo sync`. Here is the log of the resuming part after it skimmed through the available files.

```
Fetching project platform/prebuilts/go/darwin-x86
Fetching project platform/external/piex5 MiB | 11.00 KiB/s     
Fetching project platform/external/libchrome
Fetching project device/generic/goldfish
Fetching project LineageOS/android_hardware_qcom_gps00 KiB/s   
Fetching projects:  22% (142/644)  Fetching project LineageOS/contributors-cloud-generator
remote: Sending approximately 67.13 MiB ...        .00 KiB/s   
remote: Counting objects: 474, done        
remote: Finding sources: 100% (17695/17695)           
Fetching project LineageOS/android_hardware_qcom_wlan
Fetching project platform/external/pdfium
** Resuming transfer from byte position 23711744
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Reremote: Counting objects: 7289, done        
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0Re  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0reremote: Finding sources: 100% (7289/7289)           00 KiB/s   
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0Re  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0Re  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0ReFetching project platform/external/lz495.95 KiB | 32.00 KiB/s
```

**Update:** Apart from the ***resuming transfer*** thing there is a display of **percentage** as shown in the line `Fetching projects:  22% (142/644)`. This resumes from the last downloaded percentage. Also, `repo sync` as the name says, syncs the repositories to your directory, there is no reason for it to start a fresh. It seems like it's just a myth after all (that repo sync doesn't pick up from where it left) that confuses noobs like me.

**Update 2:** I also noticed that suspending using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and resuming using `fg` may not work always and might result in a network break for the paused sync.